# Uninitialized constant, compilation error, C++, GNU

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants

I've just learned what a constant is in C++ and tried the following code on Code::Blocks and it gives me the following compile-time errors:

> error: uninitialized constant 'b'[-fpermisive]

and

> no match for operator >>

(I am using namespace std).

My guess is that uninitialised constants are not allowed in C++. Why is this so?

Note: I am learning to code for the first so, I will be glad if you can explain it without referring any other language.

```
const int b;
cin >> b;
```

Comment: What could be the point of uninitialized constant? Why are you trying to assign a new value to a variable which value can not be changed?

Comment: change ```const int b;``` to ```int b;``` if you want to assign to it from std::cin

Comment: @VTT I am just trying to see what works in C++ and what doesn't. I am not sure if an uninitialized constant makes sense or not. A potential use I see is when a variable will remain constant throughout the program but, whose value must be determined at run time by the user. I think Alan Birtles provided the answer I was looking for. Maybe this question should have been phrased to ask how to assign values to constants during the run time but, when I had asked this question, I didn't know that uninitialized constants in C++ do not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constants have to be initialised when they are declared, after they have been declared they cannot be changed.

If you want to store your value that you are reading from the console in a `const` the simplest way is probably to do so via a function:

```
int readInt()
{
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    const int b = readInt();
}
```